# Deserializing JSON response to Java using RestTemplate and Jackson

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson, resttemplate

I'm running into some headaches with deserializing JSON into Java objects in a Spring Boot 1.5 app with Jackson.

As you can see below, the JSON response is an array consisting of a single JSON object with some nested attributes:

```
[
  {
    "deploymentProject": {
        "id": 57966596,
        "name": "MyApp 6.3"
    },
    "environmentStatuses": [{
            "environment": {
                "id": 57245736,
                "name": "Dev1",
                "deploymentProjectId": 57966596
            },
            "deploymentResult": {
                "deploymentVersionName": "App-51",
                "id": 59769040
            }
        },
        {
            "environment": {
                "id": 57245737,
                "name": "Dev2",
                "deploymentProjectId": 57966596
            },
            "deploymentResult": {
                "deploymentVersionName": "App-51",
                "id": 59769041
            }
        }
    ]
  }
]
```

**ResultData.java**

I don't care about the `deploymentProject` attribute so I'm only including the `environmentStatuses` in `ResultData`.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ResultData {   
  private EnvironmentStatus[] environmentStatuses;

  // Getters and setters omitted
}
```

**EnvironmentStatus.java**

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class EnvironmentStatus {

    private Environment environment;
    private DeploymentResult deployment;

    // Getters and setters omitted
}
```

**Environment.java**

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Environment {
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String deploymentProjectId;
    //Getters and setters omitted
}
```

**DeploymentResult.java**

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class DeploymentResult {
    private long id;
    private String deploymentVersionName;
    // Getters and setters omitted
}
```

When I make the call to RestTemplate in my service class, the `environmentStatuses` array is `null`:

**Service.java**

```
ResponseEntity<List<ResultData>> response = restTemplate.exchange(uriBuilder.toUriString(),
                HttpMethod.GET, null, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<ResultData>>() {});

return response.getBody();
```

Comment: what happens if you use `List<EnvironmentStatus>` instead of an array?

Comment: @mavriksc that fixed the environment attribute thanks.  the deployment info is still null though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`private DeploymentResult deployment;` is the next issue..
If you want this name in your code you need to annotate with the json structure name. or if not name it `deploymentResult`